# c# Kinect 2.0 How to detect how far a body away from the center of Kinect sensor

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

When I stand at the left hand side of the Kinect sensor, how can I calculate the distance between me and the center of Kinect sensor?[image: Details]

Comment: Old version of Kinect API allowed to detect angle from center of the sensor and that was easy way to calculate this distance having angle and distance to the object. I am not sure about 2.0 SDK but probably they did not removed this functionality

Comment: Thanks for the comment, do you have the angle name or function name so I can do some study?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me I use the `CameraSpacePoint` class.

For this I use 1 Joint for example the center of the body, and i convert it in `CameraSpacePoint`.

For example:

```
CameraSpacePoint myPoint = myJoint.Position;
Console.WriteLine(pointLeft.X);//for have your distance
```

The distance was in meter with 0 the center of Kinect Sensor

It works also with Y and Z.

You can found more information here: [CameraSpacePoint Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.cameraspacepoint.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out.

Comment: Ask me if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty straightforward.
The Kinect actually gives you the distance from the sensor, regardless of the direction...

Based on that, you just need to make the depth comparison between your point and the center point of the frame. That difference gives you the difference you are looking for.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment.